# Powershell pass variable to ArgumentList

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, teamviewer

I have some trouble passing a variable to an ArgumentList. I want to install Teamviewer via MSI with powershell:

```
Start-Process 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList $tvparams
```

i want to deploy the machine on a Teamviewer-Site and pass the variable `$serialnumber` as the alias:

```
$serialnumber = (get-ciminstance -classname win32_bios -property serialnumber).serialnumber


$tvparams = '/i','ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS="--alias  $serialnumber"'
```

The onboarding of the machine works but instead of the actual serialnumber as an alias the machine pops up as "$serialnumber" on the Teamviewer-Site as if it is a String instead of a variable.

Im fiddling with the quotes for too long so im asking now. I feel like there must be a simple solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the machine pops up as "$serialnumber" on the Teamviewer-Site as if it is a String instead of a variable.

That's because you're using `'` single-quotes - variable expansion only works in `"` double-quoted strings.

You can get around it by switching to double-quotes and escaping the literal double-quotes:

```
$tvparams = '/i',"ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS=""--alias  $serialnumber"""
```

Or by using the `-f` string format operator:

```
$tvparams = '/i',$('ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS="--alias  {0}"' -f $serialnumber)
```

Comment: @mklement0 Am I giving out more bad string marshalling advise now? :)